# CSP and X-Frame options headers issue in WordPress site

Tags: php, wordpress, x-frame-options, content-security-policy, flywheel

I have scanned my site using OWASP ZAP and got some CSP issues I have added those header in the `.htaccess`. Also I used http headers plugin for the header. but it still display missing X-Frame options header while I check it in the any online tool. Also I am getting some CSP error on the report. I'm using Flywheel hosting.

I have used this code in htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
Header always set Referrer-Policy "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "null"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization"
Header set X-Content-Security-Policy "img-src *; media-src * data:;"
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
Header always set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
Header always set Permissions-Policy "accelerometer=(), autoplay=(), camera=(), fullscreen=*, geolocation=(self), gyroscope=(), microphone=(), payment=*"
Header set X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies "none"
</IfModule>
```